Convert a spreadsheet formula to VBA and assign to a label
[me.label31.caption]  =COUNTA(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Work_Orders,(Work_Orders[Main Work Center]="TPM Packaging Technician (P4TPMPAC)")*(Work_Orders[Order Status]="Technically completed"),""),18))

How can I get the above code to work in VBA. It works great on the spreadsheet from the equal sign to the right but I need to assign the answer to the label31.caption.Thanks

You can use Worksheet.Evaluate(formulaHere) to evaluate a worksheet formula in VBA

Ok. I understand that "Evaluate" will do just that with the formula but what does that actually do?  Besides test the formula?

It returns the result of the formula

or you use
= WorksheetFunction.CountA(...

Something like this, where "Data" is the name of the sheet where your worksheet function is located:
Sub Tester()
    Dim f As String, ws As Worksheet
    
    f = "COUNTA(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Work_Orders," & _
        "(Work_Orders[Main Work Center]=""TPM Packaging Technician (P4TPMPAC)"")*" & _
        "(Work_Orders[Order Status]=""Technically completed""),""""),18))"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'for example

    Me.label31.Caption = ws.Evaluate(f)

End Sub

